# Modify a script in realtime using Chrome Developer tool?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-devtools

I try to modify `<canvas>` in realtime so I can learn fast, but because the code is used in the `<script>` so when I try to modify the code it dident get updated as i did with HTML or with the CSS.

How to make it update in real time?

Answer (score 2):

Code doesn't work like CSS or HTML (which is markup, not code, and it has a constant effect on the page). Your code is executed on page load, and if you change the code in the dev tools after it's run it's not going to un-execute your code so it can run the changed version.

At least not from the dev tools. Instead I recommend something like [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) which can watch for when you save files and then make your browser refresh itself.

Comment: ah, thank you!
NB: about external tools, i use Brackets (http://download.brackets.io/), it has Live edits, and i used it and it works, everytime the code change, the page get refreshed!
thank you again!